# Next.js Dynamic Page using useSWR

Tags: next.js, swr

I want to create dynamic pages based on the ID of a Saloon profile using useSWR and useRouter, but the data loads in after the pages are rendered.

This is my code:

```js
import useSWR from "swr";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

const fetcher = (url) => fetch(url).then((res) => res.json());

export default function FindSaloonProfile() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { id } = router.query;
  const { data, error } = useSWR(
    id ? `/api/getSaloons` : null,
    id ? fetcher : null
  );

  if (error) return <div>failed to load</div>;
  if (!data) return <div>loading...</div>;

  return <>Hello {data.name} </>;
}
```

If I `console.log(data)`, it starts getting `undefined` and loads in the data afterward, but then it is too late, as the page is already rendered.

[image: console]

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the fetcher in a function:

```
const fetcher = (url) =>
  fetch(url).then(
    async (res)=> {
      const result = await res.json();

      if (res.status !== 200) {
        return Promise.reject(result);
      } else {
        return result;
      }
    }
  );
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It seems to do the same thing though.

Comment: Have you tested?

Comment: Yes, it starts as `undefined` and ends with an object showing the data. I've added a screenshot of the console to the original description.

Answer (score 0):

Next.js is the server-side rendering framework, but mostly SWR works on the client-side merely, so it means API won't fetch data till the page loaded (or Javascript loaded).

Recently, SWR has published a new document for Next.js integration. You can check it out here.

https://swr.vercel.app/docs/with-nextjs

Let me try to keep it in a short explanation

`getStaticProps` will help you to get data on the server-side

```
 export async function getStaticProps() {
  // `getStaticProps` is executed on the server side.
  const saloons = await getSaloons() //you can call `fetcher` here too
  return {
    props: {
      fallback: {
        '/api/getSaloons': saloons
      }
    }
  }
}
```

After that, you need to import `SWRConfig` for `fallback` which is for the fetched data (React-Next.js hydration with help you to link your data with React's context)

```
export default function Page({ fallback }) {
  // SWR hooks inside the `SWRConfig` boundary will use those values.
  return (
    <SWRConfig value={{ fallback }}>
      <FindSaloonProfile />
    </SWRConfig>
  )
}
```

Lastly, you just have your usual component

```
import useSWR from "swr";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

const fetcher = (url) => fetch(url).then((res) => res.json());

export default function FindSaloonProfile() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { id } = router.query;
  //your data will get from the server initially, and then it will try to fetch again for the update
  const { data, error } = useSWR(
    id ? `/api/getSaloons` : null,
    id ? fetcher : null
  );

  if (error) return <div>failed to load</div>;
  if (!data) return <div>loading...</div>;

  return <>Hello {data.name} </>;
}
```

Hopefully, my answer is able to help you

Comment: Thanks, Nick. That seems promising. I'll test later today. Just to clarify, are we talking about the same file, or are you adding the different parts into separate files? I'm mostly talking about the Page function example. 

Should the Page function and getStaticProps live within the [id].js file, and then importing the FindSaloonProfile() ? 

Another question, should I use getServerSideProps instead? I'm dealing with profiles which could change without rebuilding?

Comment: If I try to use getStaticProps, it gives me the following error message: 
`Error: getStaticPaths is required for dynamic SSG pages and is missing for '/find-salon/[id]'.
Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/invalid-getstaticpaths-value`

Comment: If your component is a page-level one, you can call `getStaticProps` directly there. Technically, I think `gerServerSideProps` is also good, but I'm not sure how it's integrated well with SWR (please share your experimental result with me after you try it)

Comment: ah I see, I'll help you to check tomorrow (now it's midnight at my place)

Comment: Will do that, and thank you for your help. Appreciate it! Sleep well.

Comment: Do you have `getStaticPaths`. If you have that, you can try to add `fallback: 'blocking'` which is waiting for generated HTML

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242709/discussion-between-nick-vu-and-mathiassio).